# C# How to create lots of similar operators' overloads in a custom structure

Tags: c#, struct, overloading, operator-keyword

```
    public struct DecimalOrNaN
    {
        public decimal Value;
        public bool isNaN;
        public DecimalOrNaN (double D)
        {
            if (Double.IsNaN(D))
            {
                Value = default(decimal);
                isNaN = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Value = (decimal)D;
                isNaN = false;
            }             
        }
        public DecimalOrNaN(decimal D)
        {
            Value = D;
            isNaN = false;
        }
        public implicit operator DecimalOrNaN(double D)
        {
            return new DecimalOrNaN(D);
        }
        public implicit operator DecimalOrNaN(decimal D)
        {
            return new DecimalOrNaN(D);
        }
        public DecimalOrNaN operator *(int I, DecimalOrNaN D) 
        {
            return new DecimalOrNaN(D.Value * I);
        }         
    }
```

I have this struct (let's just call it DON) here which stores decimals, but has an option to have "Not a Number" in it, which regular decimal lacks. I can add the needed implicit conversions myself, but i also need it to be able to add, subtract and multiply with other DONs as well as with ints, doubles and decimals. Do I have to create each operator with each variation of parameters (int + DON, DON + int, int * DON,DON * int and so on) myself or is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: Have you considered using the nullable type "decimal?" ?

Comment: @Alan Yes, that's how I ended up doing it as a workaround, but what if I need a more complex structure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use the nullable type: decimal?. This will allow you to assign NULL to the variable to indicate it's not a number.

Documentation for this feature of the language is available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx

Comment: This is the solution I came up with for this **trivial** case, but what if I need, for example, a 3d decimal vector stored in it with the same option for NaN or something? There must be a way of doing this with the structure, is there not?

Comment: @Irdes `Nullable<3DVector>` as long as `3DVector` is a struct... the syntax `struct?` is just a shortcut for `Nullable<struct>`.